# How to compile unmanaged *.dll with makefile on windows

Tags: c++, dll

I want to compile the adplug **C/C++** source into a unmanaged *.dll to use it in .NET with PInvoke,

but I don´t get the makefile compiling to work. Could anybody please tell me how to compile that package?

Thanks for your effort!

Comment: which compiler do you use?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention the compiler name and version so I expect the Visual C++ compiler is your tool of choice. [Visual C++ compiler can be used on the command line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f35ctcxw.aspx):

```
cl /EHsc yourFile.cpp
```

Are you using make (cygwin?) or nmake? (Note: If you use cygwin/mingw you will have to get the procedures exported correctly as C-Functions to be usable by PInvoke.)

Could you add the make file you used?

What is the error message?